# How to access Kotlin DSL extensions from non-build-gradle file?

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl, gradle-kts

There are few Kotlin Extensions that come along with `org.gradle.kotlin.dsl` like
`android` or `publishing` etc. Say, for `publishing`, the extension is defined as below

```
fun org.gradle.api.Project.`publishing`(configure: org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension.() -> Unit): Unit =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.configure("publishing", configure)
```

That means within my`build.gradle.kts` I can call

```
publishing {
    // blablabla
}
```

In my case, I have a separate file that handles publishing defined as `random.gradle.kts` and is located at totally random directory.

Here, I want to access this `publishing` extension but not able to do it.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

To give another example `android` is also not accessible.
In my `build.gradle.kts` I can access `android` but in my `random.gradle.kts` I am not able to do it.

`android` extension is defined as below

```
val org.gradle.api.Project.`android`: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension get() =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("android") as com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension
```

In fact, LibraryExtension is also not accessible.

So, how to *pass* or *import* those extensions to my `random.gradle.kts`?

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
    //build.gradle.kts tested with gradle 6.7
    
    subprojects {
      afterEvaluate {
        (extensions.findByType(com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension::class)
          ?: extensions.findByType(com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension::class))?.apply {
    
          println("Found android subproject $name")
          lintOptions.isAbortOnError = false
          compileSdkVersion(30)
          
          if (this is com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension) 
            println("$name is an application")
          
          if (this is com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension) {
    
            val publishing =
              extensions.findByType(PublishingExtension::class.java) ?: return@afterEvaluate
    
            val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
              archiveClassifier.set("sources")
              from(sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs)
            }
    
            afterEvaluate {
              publishing.apply {
                val projectName = name
                publications {
                  val release by registering(MavenPublication::class) {
                    components.forEach {
                      println("Publication component: ${it.name}")
                    }
                    from(components["release"])
                    artifact(sourcesJar.get())
                    artifactId = projectName
                    groupId = ProjectVersions.GROUP_ID
                    version = ProjectVersions.VERSION_NAME
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```